# $G_\delta$-diagonal

Tags: gn.general-topology, soft-question, counterexamples

Could one find a counterexample that a topology space X is Tychonoff, seperable but hasn't

a $G_\delta$-diagonal? A topology space has a $G_\delta$-diagonal when there is a sequence

${G_n}$ of open sets belonging to $X^2$ with the diagonal $\Delta$ = $\cap{G_n}$.

Comment: Dear John... where are all your questions coming from? most of them feel like homework problems and surprisingly only two of those have been closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The product space $[0,1]^\kappa$ for $\aleph_1\le\kappa\le\mathfrak c$ is compact $T_2$ (hence Tychonoff) and separable (by the Hewitt–Marczewski–Pondiczery theorem), but it does not have a $G_\delta$ diagonal (in fact, if a compact $T_2$ space has a $G_\delta$ diagonal, then its unique uniform structure has a countable fundamental system, hence it is metrizable).

Comment: By $\mathfrak c$ I meant the cardinality of the continuum ($2^{\aleph_0}$), which is indeed always uncountable.